# How to deal with corrupted .tar.lrz file

Tags: compression

I have a file `file.tar.lrz` and tried to unzip it via `lrzuntar file.tar.lrz` but it gives an error: "Not an lrzip file" with `lrunzip`.

I also tried to open it with file roller. `file file.tar.lrz` says just `data`.

Any ideas of how to debug this?

Comment: What do `lrz -i file.tar.lrz` and `file file.tar..rz` output ?

Comment: I don't have a command called `lrz`. In which ubuntu package is this tool?

Comment: :) I don't use ubuntu.

Comment: You don't need `lrz` it gives the same options as the more standard `lrzip`, in other words `lrz -i` and `lrzip -i` would give the same information. 

There are lots of ways to determine the type of compression that was used (read the header with `hexdump` for example) but `file` should have returned that to you. I'd guess file.tar.lrz isn't a standard compression file, or perhaps is corrupted. If `file` returns `data` I think you're pretty much SOL